# Cannot move apps to SD Card

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, sd-card, app2sd, motorola-moto-g3

I own a Motorola Moto G 3rd generation upgraded to Marshmallow with an SD card plugged in (formatted as internal storage) and I am not able to get the apps to install there. I tried app2sd and I am able to relocate some of them but the sheer amount of the ones I cannot has filled my telephone's internal storage to the brim. I know that I could solve it by rooting the phone ( it's risky and warranty is voided), however I was looking for another way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way unless you void your warranty.. Change the ROM to any custom ROMs it will solve the problem.

Comment: I'm not that sure that really *any* custom ROM supports moving apps to SD. The only "sure" answer I'm aware of is rooting and using an app like [link2sd](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/link2sd/info) (there are a few apps of that category). Though I'm not sure how that works with adoptable-storage (OP indicated to use that option).